# WPF DataGrid Filter does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I filter my DataGrid?
This code does not work:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetSource();
    }

    private void FilterTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void SetSource()
    {
        CollectionViewSource Sorted = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = MainDB.CurDB.Requests };
        Sorted.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Id", ListSortDirection.Descending));
        Sorted.Filter += Sorted_Filter;
        MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = Sorted.View;
    }

    private void Sorted_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
```

The Exception I get:

[image]

> "System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView" It does not support filtering

Update:
The filter is now working, but now I get the following error, that breaks the columns:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
> 'Changing Date' property not found on 'object' ''RequestsRow'
> (HashCode=56483442)'. BindingExpression:Path=Changing Date;
> DataItem='RequestsRow' (HashCode=56483442); target element is
> 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

The problem occurs when some cells remain empty

My DataSet. No other classes i have:

[image]

The problem was solved by replacing "SM Id" "SM_Id", etc.

Comment: Try this : `ICollectionView Sorted= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainDB.CurDB.Requests);` instead of `CollectionViewSource Sorted = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = MainDB.CurDB.Requests };`

Comment: ICollectionView Sorted = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainDB.CurDB.Requests); Sorted.Filter = item => true;  Throws Exception("
The method is not supported")

Comment: Ok, try `ICollectionView Sorted= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainDB.CurDB.Requests.AsEnumerable()); Sorted.Filter = item => true;`

Comment: Thanks. Filtering began to work, but now I get an error that I described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<DataRow> requests = MainDB.CurDB.Requests.Select().ToList();
CollectionViewSource Sorted = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = requests };
```

Comment: "Requests" is DataTable

Comment: Causes of this error:   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SM Id' property not found on 'object' ''RequestsRow' (HashCode=45629785)'. BindingExpression:Path=SM Id; DataItem='RequestsRow' (HashCode=45629785); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String'). It breaks the DataGrid columns "SM Id", "Creation Date" and "Changing Date"

Comment: It looks like you have a class called RequestRow. You need to manually map the DataRow fields to the fields of your RequestRow class. Something like this:
    var requests = (from dr in MainDB.CurDB.Requests.AsEnumerable()
                select new RequestRow 
                {
                    SM_Id = dr.Field<int>("SM_Id"),
                    //...all the fields you need
                }).ToList();
    CollectionViewSource Sorted = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = requests };

Comment: Thanks.  Filtering began to work, but now I get an error that I described.

Comment: The error says that in the RequestsRow class, the property "Changing Date" is missing. You have to do the same as with the SM Id, set the property "Changing_Date" of the class to the value of the field "Changing Date" (as I showed before in the example with SM_Id).

Comment: Yes. I already did it. I wrote, "etc." Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Oh, ok. Welcome :-)